# Is There Any Way to Send A POST Request To Google Apps Script On A Html Page?

Tags: google-apps-script, post, cors

**What I encounter**

I am trying to send a POST request to my Google Apps script App I deploy on an HTML page. Just like everyone else, I encounter the CORs issue. It used to work fine a couple of days ago, but the CORs error has kept popping up since yesterday.

**What I've Tried Already**

I've tried every code snippet on the Internet, including the following one.

I add "redirect:'follow'" to my request, and add 'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' to my header. Also, I set the app to execute as "me" to allow access to "anonymous".

**My Client Side Code Snippet**

```
fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/scriptID/exec', {
  redirect: 'follow',
  method: 'POST',
  body: 'name=John&time=2pm',
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
  },
  body: 'name=John&time=2pm'
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

**My Google Apps Script Side Code Snippet**

```
function doPost(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Hello World.");
}
```

However, the same error keeps popping up

Access to fetch at 'https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=RKhCMzKlHGhMyMLduJ9h1mEqXXahhcVI_B1XUiY-uXYCA2avW6QEFIzPNuAOuqiCZxNnefexPmskG-pqs9CPzeLZxtrYybMhm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnArw_oV2MpMq3qjVF8H4XS9_NTQKCR_pNm9X1iIkiAGMBwUfPQF5TBrDregaghr_F4OeYIU5d4Ai-OP0kwNgroizGK8DWxIQmdz9Jw9Md8uu&lib=MQPbBZFGo2AGvsxr1HURYz_BIqPDiKvt_' (redirected from 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyf_P8NNxR34tNj-TS617RnFWsOtWQjTAdLUQPVc0TWOoxAk3K4a5EPRa0LrmXy_qwBhg/exec') from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value '.....

**Reference:**

[Blocked by cors Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56502086/google-app-script-web-app-get-and-post-request-blocked-by-cors-policy?rq=3)

[Sending Post Request To Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62888148/sending-post-requests-to-a-google-apps-script)

[Sending Cross Domain Control Stopped Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525860/cross-domain-requests-stopped-working-due-to-no-access-control-allow-origin-he)

Comment: Can I ask you about the setting of your Web Apps? From `Also, I set the app to execute as "me" to allow access to "anonymous".`, I guessed that `Execute as:` is `Me`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, what is the value of `Who has access to the app:`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. Because, in your showing script, I think that when `Who has access to the app:` is `Anyone`, the script works. Even if you use `Anyone`, an error occurs. Please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps and test it again.

Comment: By the way, I deeply apologize that my 2 answers were not useful for your situation. I would like to think of a solution by correctly understanding your situation. I apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your current situation.

Comment: Provide `curl -v -X POST -d "..."` output...

Comment: @Tanaike Correct,  even with the setting "Execute as Me" and "Who has access to the app: Anyone" , the error persists.

Comment: @TheMaster I think that is not related to my question, sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike I believe this problem is reproducible. And it worked just fine a few days ago, but the error has kept popping up since yesterday.

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. About `I believe this problem is reproducible. And it worked just fine a few days ago, but the error has kept popping up since yesterday`, in that case, when you reflect the latest script to Web Apps by deploying again, what result will you obtain? By the way, is your actual script the same as your showing script except for the Web Apps URL?

Comment: @TheMaster I think that when it requests Web Apps with a curl command, `curl -v -X POST -d "..." output...` cannot correctly request Web Apps. In that case, I think that In that case, `curl -v -L -d "sample" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId}/exec"`. This report might be useful for understanding the request flow to Web Apps.  [Ref](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-flow-of-request-to-web-apps-created-by-google-apps-script-ac49e80f7c6b)

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, the error persists even though I deploy again, and obtain the new URL. The actual script is the same as my showing script.

Comment: Thank you for replying I apologize for the inconvenience. From `Yes, `, I understood that your actual script is the same with your showing script. In this case, I think that it is required to correctly understand your actual situation. So, can you provide your current Google Apps Script project and your Javascript for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Sure, [Click Here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyf_P8NNxR34tNj-TS617RnFWsOtWQjTAdLUQPVc0TWOoxAk3K4a5EPRa0LrmXy_qwBhg/exec)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I think that is the Web Apps URL. I asked about your current Google Apps Script project including your showing script and your Javascript for correctly replicating your current issue. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your script from Web Apps URL. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Pardon poor English proficiency, too. [Click Here](https://script.google.com/d/1RqwRXkEj007lLunD-4FzdctwdagEWfjwODzLEZBN9t0gR0U4LKoJRYBZ/edit?usp=sharing) for doPost and  [Click Here](https://script.google.com/d/1o9U3QPtQHYPf2S77i4I9xOohHcZUHFQMkfdh0c-3mNPohv75VXrl-GgW/edit?usp=sharing) for HTML Page(index.html)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will check it.

Comment: When I asked `is your actual script the same as your showing script except for the Web Apps URL?`, you said `yes`. But, when I saw your current script, unfortunately, it seems that your provided script and Javascript are different from your showing scripts. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill again. Can you test your showing scripts?

Comment: @Tanaike I put the fetch part in a button in the HTML file `index.html`. Over there, you can see a function called `fetchInfo()`, and that is where you find the fetch part. I believe that is my showing script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't udnerstand your reply. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry for the misunderstanding, I tried my best to clarify my statement. Please [click here](https://script.google.com/d/1o9U3QPtQHYPf2S77i4I9xOohHcZUHFQMkfdh0c-3mNPohv75VXrl-GgW/edit?usp=sharing) to check the `index.html` , and [click here](https://script.google.com/d/1RqwRXkEj007lLunD-4FzdctwdagEWfjwODzLEZBN9t0gR0U4LKoJRYBZ/edit?usp=sharing) to check my `doPost(e)`Function

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your newly provided scripts by removing the unused scripts, I could confirm "Hello World." in the console when I ran the function `fetchInfo()` of the Javascript. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for replying. Maybe there is something I overlook. Just want to make sure, do you test the Client side HTML page on the Google Apps Script IDE? Because the error persists even when I open up a new file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `do you test the Client side HTML page on the Google Apps Script IDE?`, I tested the HTML of your client Google Apps Script project. The HTML is opened from the Web Apps URL retrieved from the IDE. In your situation, when you test your Web Apps by the methods except for the fetch API, what result did you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike Much Thanks for your kind help. The problem was solved after I switched to a different google account.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike I understand the redirection(I did miss the `-L`). I thought that the script might be erroring out or due to incorrect permissions, be redirected to a Google login page.... That's why I  thought the ``v``erbose output of `curl` might be helpful.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. I agree with `-v` option. By the way, in the curl command, when `-X POST` is used, the request after the redirect is the POST method. But, in the current stage, Web Apps uses the GET method after the redirect even when `doPost` is requested. So, in order to achieve this, with `-L` option, it is required to remove `-X POST` and use `-d` option. When only the `-d` option is used with `-L` option, the GET method is used after the redirect. By this, the value is returned from `doPost`.

Comment: @Tanaike Got it..Thanks.