# Access Google spreadsheet from Chrome Extension: CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, cors, cross-domain

I have a Google spreadsheet and a Google script app that has method *doGet(e)* which returns spreadsheet content in JSON. Google app is published, and by calling URL I receive totally valid JSON i'm looking for.

Now, I'd like my Chrome extension to call that URL and receive all the data.

It's been working a while ago, but as of this moment, it crashes with an error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec' from origin 'https://www.YYY.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've been digging around for a while, tried several solutions, but it seems most of them are related to the backend, which I don't have access to (its still Google script app). Are there any workarounds?

EDIT: no luck with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587453/xmlhttprequest-blocked-by-cors-policy-when-posting-data-to-a-web-app) option. My code (tried *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*, *multipart/form-data*, *text/plain* - got the same results):

```
$.ajax({    
  url:'https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  success:function (result) {
    *** 
  }
```

Comment: Use simple requests. See linked duplicate above

Comment: @TheMaster That didn't work for me, added details

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, for example, is this information useful for your situation? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/a72aab0242012362c46ec69031c720d5#ajax And in your case, the Web Apps is required to be deployed as `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous`. Please be careful this.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks a ton, that's it. I've changed `Who has access to the app` to Anyone and got what I've been looking for!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: I'd love to, as I've struggled a lot - but @TheMaster locked this question as a duplicate, although it's definitely not.

Comment: [Edit] to show the  original `Execute the app as:` and  the original `Who has access to the app:` you used first. I still believe it's a partial duplicate as I still don't think `json` will work and  will still throw  the same error(if not reply back). For future reference, Always include all steps to reproduce the problem as written in [mcve] to avoid closing as duplicate. @Tanaike If you feel  any question needs to be reopened or wrongly closed, feel free to reopen as you  wish. I won't/don't mind :)

Comment: @TheMaster I've voted to reopen it as well - I'll include `Execute the app as` in the answer, as I believe that is the proper place for that info, not the issue description. But I need the question to be reopened first :)

Comment: What I meant was: You should have included  what the original configuration was in the question("original" Execute the app as: and the "original" Who has access to the app:). Only then the answer would even be valid, if at all. If the question never included what the original configuration was, how would the answerer know something was amiss with the configuration.

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks. Now I noticed that this question had been reopened. By this, OP can post the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) for a great hint!

Apparently, the issue was in publishing settings. Basically, I did 2 steps to solve it:

1. As mentioned by [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster), i've switched request ContentType to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. For more details, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62624680/1154733) answer.
2. As mentioned by [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike), i've switched the publishing settings to *Execute the app as: Me* and W*ho has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous*.

[image]

Comment: It saved me! thanks